# How can I easily delete all objects in a Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have the choice of doing a migration, but I would prefer to delete everything in my defaultRealm(). How can I do this easily?

```
realm.deleteObject(object)
```

is the only function along with .deleteObjects.

I have tried the following code:

Method 1

```
realm.deleteObjects(RLMObject.objectsInRealm(realm, withPredicate: NSPredicate(value: true)))
```

Method 2

```
        realm.deleteObjects(Dog.allObjectsInRealm(realm))
        realm.deleteObjects(Person.allObjectsInRealm(realm))
        realm.deleteObjects(Goal.allObjectsInRealm(realm))
        realm.deleteObjects(Goals.allObjectsInRealm(realm))
```

Both fail to prevent the migration exception.

Comment: Hey Captain, are you doing this on ios or android? Those methods do delete all the objects but you will still run into the migration issues.

Comment: A quick way to do this on simulator/phone is to just delete the app from the home screen

Comment: iOS! And where can I learn more about migration?

Comment: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.86.0/#migrations

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Use [`deleteAll()`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-objects):

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you guys should add that to the documentation!

Comment: This is documented in Realm's API docs: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/deleteAllObjects, which are more comprehensive than Realm's getting started documentation at https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest.

Comment: I think the API changed a bit. For me to remove all objects using `RealmSwift`this worked: `try! realm.write { realm.deleteAll() }`

Comment: @JohnB. Updated answer.

Comment: if the realm notification still running that time, it might cause crash, if directly use realm.deleteAll()

Answer (score 16):

As of [v0.87.0](http://realm.io/news/realm-cocoa-0.87.0/), there is a [`deleteAllObjects`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/deleteAllObjects) method on [`RLRealm`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.87.0/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html) that will clear the Realm of all objects.

Comment: @cesarferreira I recommend you file an issue with Realm (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues) then.

Comment: @cesarferreira can you share the code in github issues?

Comment: what do you mean with share github issue?

Comment: If you can create a github issue you can copy and paste some code in there to show where it's not working for you

Answer (score 11):

Things have moved on in the Realm world - in case anyone comes across this now, there is a property that can be set:

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true
```

It then does as advertised. (btw: a lot of the syntax above has changed in case you are trying any of the other methods)

The Github PR https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3463

Answer (score 5):

I think removing the Realm DB file is the valid answer considering that the question was about removing a whole storage rather than migrating it.

Here is a quick Swift code for that (as of Swift 2.1 and Realm 0.96.2):

```
if let path = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path {
    try! NSFileManager().removeItemAtPath(path)
}
```

I use this code in the DEBUG version of the app if the migration error happens on loading the storage and then I recreate the storage. During development the schema can change a lot, so it would be too cumbersome to bother with migration all the time.