# How to delete all objects in Realm at run time

Tags: ios, realm

How can i delete all objects in Realm at run time ?

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185679/how-can-i-easily-delete-all-objects-in-a-realm) but the answer can only be used at the launch of the app. But I want to delete everything at launch time. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>For now you will need to do this for each object type:</strike>

RLMResults *arrayOfObjects = [Person allObjects];
    [realm deleteObjects:arrayOfObjects];

We're working on a way to make this easier

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm deleteAllObjects];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: You can use [realm deleteAllObects]; now

Comment: Ah, I was actually hoping for a different answer, since your original answer removed all Persons, I was wondering how you'd do that with one type :). But I guess this is a better response to the OP.

Comment: Ah, yea still the same if you want to just delete a specific group of objects