# Delete Realm database completely in React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a function in my app where the user reset the account whenever he/she desires to do so and I want to delete the whole realm local database and start over with creating a new one after completed process of deleting it.

This is not for migration but rather wipe out the whole database and start over as if the app was deleted and installed again.

Is there any way to do this, I can't seem to find information on this

My code is written in React Native so this is RealmJS

Comment: Classic Realm or MongoDB Realm (sync)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26244843/9231356

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Just a caveat that this code will not work if Realm has been 'talked to' before this code. e.g. as soon as you app does *anything* with Realm, it remembers that connection. Even if you delete the files, it will re-create itself. So, this code needs to run before any connection to realm is made.

Comment: So you are saying that this could work if I create a code where the user "Delete Account", the app restarts but this time I run the code above before anything else ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use an encryption key for the database so I somehow need to delete it while the key (or realm instance for corresponding key) is in memory..

Comment: @tompa yes. As long as that code runs *before* making any other connection to Realm it will work. Otherwise the data will re-populate.